# Languages with a grammatical distinction between abstract and concrete nouns

Tags: grammar, list-of-languages, parts-of-speech, nouns

Are there any languages making a *grammatical* distinction between abstract and concrete nouns?
I suppose this should boil down to the question about the existence of languages having a *morpheme* signalling an abstract or concrete noun but you never know (maybe there are some crazy ones making the distinction with word order, phonology...)

Comment: There are languages that have abstract, collective etc. noun grammemes (i.e. grammatical markers) but I think you need an example of a binary opposition?

Comment: Not an accurate answer to your question, but Japanese verbs *aru* and *iru* have -human and +human participants in binary semantics approach.

Comment: In some languages, such as Greek, abstract nouns tend to be one particular gender/class. I don't know of any languages with a class used only for abstract nouns, but it seems like something that could well exist in the thousands of minority languages out there.

Comment: Abstract nouns in English tend to be mass nouns.

Answer (score 2):

Some verbs in Russian, like iskat', search for, uses the accusative case for specific objects like "I'm looking for a book" and the genitive case for abstract objects like "I'm looking for peace and quiet". Ya ishchu knigu vs Ya ishchu mira I tishiny.

Comment: what makes "a book" less abstract than "peace and quiet"?

Comment: Thanks... But _quiet_ is [quite](http://chompchomp.com/terms/concretenoun.htm) concrete

Comment: @jaam: not if "concrete" involves senses.  you can't hear silence.

Comment: @mobileink Really? If you hear nothing, you hear silence

Comment: @jaam:  what is it to "hear nothing"?

Comment: @mobileink Do you insist on the meaninglessness of a sentence like _I hear nothing_? It's used all the time. A complete silence being physically problematic is besides the point. Many concepts (unicorns, etc.) are physically problematic but linguistically (and psychologically) OK (as long as we can imagine them)

Comment: @jaam:  telax. I didn't say anything about the meaningfulness of any sentences.  I asked you to tell us what it is to hear nothing.  it sounds like you may be mixing up grammatical form and meaning. a grammatical direct object does not a sensory object make - that was your toic, no?

Comment: sorry, typos: relax not telax, topic, not toic.